# Structuring the relay spec viewer in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

My Schema.graphql of Relay, this is the structure I'm trying to achieve,

```
type Root {
  viewer: Viewer
}

type Viewer {
  categories(id: ID): Category
  subCategories(CategoryId: ID!) : [SubCategory]
  items(SubCategoryId: ID): Item
  shopItems(ShopId: ID, SubCategoryId:ID): Item
}
```

Now the server, my viewer.js looks like this,

```
const Viewer = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'viewer',
  fields: {
    categories,
    subCategories,
    Items,
    shopItems,
  },
});
```

and the root is,

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'query',
  fields: {
    viewer: {
      type: Viewer,
    },
  },
});
```

It is giving me the structure I want, but I cannot resolve anything from rootQuery, viewer simply returns null because I'm not resolving the viewer type in rootQuery. Any ideas how to implement this Relay spec structure properly? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of showing the code of your resolver (perhaps you're using the default), this ought to help.

You're using an accepted pattern of having a root `viewer` object, whose "type" is the real root query type. That type needs to give its fields a way of resolving to your real architecture. For instance:

```
const subCategories = {
  type: GraphQLList({ ofType: SubCategory }),
  arguments: {
    CategoryId: { type: GraphQLNonNull({ ofType: GraphQLID }),
  },
  resolve(rootValue, { CategoryId }, context, info) {
    // look stuff up based on CategoryId and return it
  },
};

const Viewer = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'viewer',
  fields: {
    categories,
    subCategories,
    Items,
    shopItems,
  },
});
```

Comment: Well I have already done that. Those fields are already defined and im importing them.

Comment: Grapqhl wants me to resolve the viewer field in the root query. I obviously cant do that.

Comment: Surely you can do that, just supply your own resolver function to `graphql`?

Comment: I will have to resolve viewer type which has the fields categories, subcategories etc that are already resolved. If I dont resolve viewer, the query returns null because it expects to resolve viewer.

Comment: Have you tried the pattern given here? http://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/ The various fields of `Viewer` would have resolver functions as above, which would return suitably-created JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, solved it by resolving viewer like this,

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'query',
  fields: {
    viewer: {
      type: Viewer,
      resolve(viewer, args) {
       return {viewer: viewer}
     }
    },
  },
});
```